# Safari downloads files via FTP as Unknown.dms

Tags: safari, file, ftp

This is a rather recent issue: when I download a file from my web server via ftp it gets saved as Unknown.dms
macOS: 10.12.6
Safari: 11.0

Interestingly, downloading the same file with e.g. Chrome works flawless.
One of my download links: ftp://v473.vanager.de/file_format_examples/ASD/old_format/DC.013

If the file is archived as zip first, then the download works, giving the correct file name to the downloaded file (automatic un-archiving of the download).

Comment: And your question is? Most probably you need to ensure that the web/ftp server sets the correct Mime type for the file.

Comment: I don't think the mime type is the issue here. The issue is that Safari does not give the correct file name to the downloaded file, while e.g. Chrome does that. The question is obviously: why is this happening and how to solve it?

Comment: I just tried, downloads as DC.013 here (Safari 11.0.1 (13604.3.5))

Comment: Same problem, this link and others, Safari  11.1.2 (12605.3.8.1).  Note that this may be a 10.12 Finder issue as I believe Safari hands FTP off to the Finder.